# Python tkinter change how to change cursor without the use of canvas/widgets?

Tags: python, tkinter, cursor

**I want to change how to cursor looks while the mouse is in a range of pixels, and when it gets out of that range, it changes to normal (I *dont* want to use the canvas/other widgets "cursor=" kwarg)**

```
from tkinter import*

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500+0+0')

def change_cursor(event):
    if event.x in range(450,500):
        #change how the cursor looks


root.bind('<B1-Motion>', change_cursor)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why not to use `root.config(cursor="watch")`? This will show a "busy" cursor. There are lots of other cursors in Tkinter: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_cursors.htm

Comment: `if event.x in range(450, 500): root.config(cursor="watch"); else: root.config(cursor="")`

Comment: And change `"<B1-Motion>"` event to `"<Motion>"` Otherwise it will react only while mouse is being dragged.

Comment: The way to change the cursor is by setting the `cursor` option. Since you say you don't want to do that, there's no way to accomplish your goal using tkinter. Can you explain why you need a solution that doesn't configure the `cursor` option?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the only way to do what you want is to use `root.config(cursor="cursor_name")`. `"watch"` cursor_name is for the busy cursor and `""` cursor_name is for the normal cursor.

Also you need to change the `"<B1-Motion>"` event (mouse **dragging**, with left mouse button pressed) to just `"<Motion>"` event (mouse movement, it's not necessary to press any mouse buttons).

And, of course, you need to change the cursor back (`else` block)

Here's the fixed code:

```
from tkinter import*


root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500+0+0")

def change_cursor(event):
    if event.x in range(450, 500):
        root.config(cursor="watch")
    else:
        root.config(cursor="")


root.bind("<Motion>", change_cursor)
root.mainloop()
```